# I cannot identify the 'VBA.Date' code component

Tags: excel, vba

I have found many blocks of code that contain`VBA.Date`, for example;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub
Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Format(VBA.Date, “MM/DD/YYYY”)
End Sub
```

Or

```
Sub YearSheets()
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
Do
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = Format(VBA.Date + i, “MM-DD-YYYY”)
i = i + 1
Loop Until i = 365
End Sub
```

I have tried these steps:

1. I have pushed <kbd>F1</kbd> for VBA's help but it shows "Keyword Not Found".
2. Searched my VBA books but no one shows something because they take such a piece of information as unimportant or too easy (I guess).
3. I have tried to Google it --> You can imagine what happens with a combination of such common words.
4. I have pushed <kbd>F2</kbd> in the VBE Window and opened the Object Browser
   i.  I searched for VBA and I got the library ... not very bright
   ii. I searched for the Date Property and I found it to be preceded by the DateTime Module and going more in seniority from the VBA Library.

   Question-born-from-question: Is it possible to be the VBA library here **VBA**.Date?

Frustrating-thing-that-happens: Once I type VBE IntelliSense shows Date Property, so it's hard-coded somewhere in my machine.

What really is **`VBA`**`.Date` - an object, a library that can be entered as as object?

Comment: Make sure that you don't "miss the forest for the trees" when doing programming.

Comment: Yes! I am a detail freak what can i say...? That's how i buy the most valuable birds in the most discounted prices:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VBA.Date` and `VBA.Time` are [functions that return the current date and the current time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227564%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), respectively.

Comment: Yes but is the VBA component an object? What is is. In the link that you have i cannot see any example with VBA.(something) so i can find out what it is...                                                    well i know that we have objects, properties, functions could you please elaborate more on what do you mean by saying types(?)       Please can you tell me what is **VBA**.Date here................... Is it all of it called a type as --->VBA.Date<---

Comment: Think of them as "static" functions written on the VBA "class" that return a `Date` object or a `Time` object, except that you don't actually have to say `VBA.Date` (you can simply say Date, and VBA will figure out that you mean `VBA.Date` from the context).

Comment: Dear Robert Harvey i can understand that it will give me a date object or time object. I also understand that they can stand alone as Date() and Time() but what i am really trying to figure out is:           AS what **VBA**.(something) stands in the code..? Well i am constantly seeing it in blocks of code and the thing that i don't know that is constantly making me unhappy                           So the VBA is a class? Does this mean it is an object?              (as you probably have figured out by now it's a little bit of a vice to me to clear that point out:P)

Comment: It is! But your answer was the more intuitive to me truly! In VBA, a class is defined in class module and serves as a template for an object right? I think i am getting close! Thank you for your very powerful patience :P

Answer (score 3):

Date() and Time() are Properties of the DateTime Class. Found in Excel VBA. They are of DataType Variant that contain the current system date when Date is used and current system time when Time is used.

They do not need to be preceeded by the VBA or the DateTime in order to be used they can simply be used with the terms Date, and Time.

Date, and if the calendar is Gregorian, Date$ behavior is unchanged by the Calendar property setting. If the calendar is Hijri, Date$ returns a 10-character string of the form mm-dd-yyyy, where mm (01-12), dd (01-30) and yyyy (1400-1523) are the Hijri month, day and year. The equivalent Gregorian range is Jan 1, 1980 through Dec 31, 2099.

In the future the best way to get information on specific function, properties, methods, classes and other members of the VBA Language you can use the Object Browser.

Marked one is the object browser and when clicked on will open this window (it can also be accessed with pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>) In this window enter what you are searching for

[image]

One you get results scroll through and look for a more specific item:

[image]

Now there are 2 points in the above image:

```
1) At the bottom of the screen it gives basic detail about this item, in this case
   it states that it belongs to the `DateTime` Class, and is a property of that 
   class, and that it is a Variant. 

2) Also in the picture above I have right clicked on the item and selected Help from 
   the context menu, this will bring up even more details about this item.
```

[image]

As you can see here Microsoft has built in support for this item and gives you details on what it is, what data type it would use and what it returns. Also, how to use and some common notes for when you use it!

Comment: Yes but what **VBA**.(something) stands in the code?...as an object? Sorry for the persistence but i have seen this expression in various code blocks and i always want to know how it stands when i see it...i guess it's getting a little bit of a vice

Comment: As I stated in my Answer it is a function that Returns a Variant. Not an object.

Comment: Why does `VBA.Date` work?  Is there an alias in there somewhere?

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant The `VBA` portion of it is a library, or a DLL, you can research this furthur, but it basically means that it is pre written code for use in other programs, it allows other programs that are *referenceing* that library access to all properties, methods, classes, and object that have been developed and compiled inside of that Library.

Comment: If `Date` is a function on `DateTime`, then why does `VBA.Date` return the current date?  And why are you not required to say `DateTime.Date` or `DateTime.Time`, or use an instance of `DateTime` to call `Date` or `Time`?

Comment: I have concluded dear friends that the VBA portion is a class like these ones described http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx   Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @RobertHarvey The same reason why EVERY member of the DateTime class can be called that way (Now, DateDiff,DAteAdd, DateSerial, DateValue,Day,Hour,minute,Second to name a few) because inside the DLL they are defined as global variables. you can also use the Object Browser to view other global commands.

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant did you not read my comment where I informaed you VBA is a Library not a class... If you Go under tools, then click references this will list all the libraries available on your computer, VBA being one.

Comment: Huh?  `Date` is a global variable?  Then why does Microsoft [call it a function?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227564(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: Oh sorry i confused these two terms but now i have made the distinction! So a library can actually stand as in code before a property! I try to read every line of explanation with the greatest of attention!

Comment: @RobertHarvey Variable was the wrong word, I just meant that is is globally defined in VBA, along with MANY other Variable,Functions,Subs, and Classes.

Comment: So `Date` must be declared twice; once in the `DateTime` class, and again in the global `VBA` namespace (which probably just points to the `DateTime` class's `Date` method).

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant You can learn more about [What a Library Is Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing))

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sounds logical to me.

Comment: VBA.dll is a library probably written in C++. Inside the library is an object named "VBA". This object doesn't have any properties or methods of its own, it only inherits all the other objects in the library. There are a half dozen other classes in the library that contain properties and methods. The VBA object and all the other objects are publicly instantiable (you can type VBA.DateTime.Date or just DateTime.Date). So, VBA.dll is the library and VBA is a public facing class inside the library that inherits all the other classes.

Answer (score 0):

In your editor Tools / References you'll see 'Visual Basic For Applications' is selected. I have absoutely no proof but my idle conjecture is that this is where your VBA.Date (and VBA, everything) lies. Furthermore your F2 investigations show you the truth - It's in the VBA module there. Note you can use `VBA.Date` or just `Date` and they are the same thing.

In short it's hard coded in that DLL file referred to in Tools/References.